# Pass custom screenshot consumer though json config

Tags: c#, automated-tests, atata

**Hi,**

I use Atata framework with ExtentReports, based on this project: https://github.com/atata-framework/atata-samples/tree/master/ExtentReports

Now I want switch from fluent context build to json config. My fluent context build looks like:

```
    AtataContext.GlobalConfiguration
        .UseChrome()
            .WithArguments("--start-maximized")
        .WithLocalDriverPath()
        .WithFixOfCommandExecutionDelay()
        .UseCulture("en-US")
        .UseAllNUnitFeatures()
        .AddDebugLogging()
        .AddScreenshotFileSaving()
            .WithArtifactsFolderPath()
        .AddLogConsumer(new ExtentLogConsumer())
            .WithMinLevel(LogLevel.Info)
        .EventSubscriptions.Add(new ExtentScreenshotFileEventHandler());
    
    AtataContext.GlobalConfiguration.AutoSetUpDriverToUse();
```

I can implement via json config almost all, except this line:

```
.EventSubscriptions.Add(new ExtentScreenshotFileEventHandler());
```

My config:

```
{
  "driver": {
    "type": "chrome",
    "alias": "chrome",
    "options": {
      "arguments": [ "start-maximized" ],
      "userProfilePreferences": {
        "download.default_directory": "{artifacts}"
      }
    }
  },
  "culture": "en-US",
  "useAllNUnitFeatures": true,
  "logConsumers": [
    {
      "type": "nlog-file",
      "folderPath": "{artifacts}",
      "minLevel": "Debug"
    },
    {
      "type": "AtataUITests1.Core.Reporting.ExtentLogConsumer, AtataUITests1",
      "minLevel": "Info"
    }
  ],
  "screenshotConsumers": [
    {
      "type": "file",
      "folderPath": "{artifacts}"
    }
  ]
}
```

When I try to add new `screenshotConsumer` to json:

```
  "screenshotConsumers": [
    {
      "type": "file",
      "folderPath": "{artifacts}"
    },
    {
      "type": "AtataUITests1.Core.Reporting.ExtentScreenshotFileEventHandler, AtataUITests1"
    }
  ]
```

it shows error:

```
System.InvalidCastException : Unable to cast object of type 'AtataUITests1.Core.Reporting.ExtentScreenshotFileEventHandler' to type 'Atata.IScreenshotConsumer'.
```

My question is: is it possible to pass this custom screenshot consumer via json?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ExtentScreenshotFileEventHandler` is not a screenshot consumer but an event handler. So it should be placed in "eventSubscriptions" section as below:

```
"eventSubscriptions": [
  {
    "handlerType": "AtataUITests1.Core.Reporting.ExtentScreenshotFileEventHandler, AtataUITests1"
  }
]
```

There is also an example on [Atata.Configuration.Json / JSON Schema](https://github.com/atata-framework/atata-configuration-json#json-schema) section.

Comment: That right, didn't notice this, thanks!

Comment: You're welcome.